# Cannot authenticate school user Office 365 account when attempting setup OneDrive on Windows 7 PC

Tags: authentication, onedrive, windows-7

Have downloaded OneDrive to a Windows 7 machine (eventually will be replaced by Windows 10 machine after migrated data to OneDrive).

I could migrate data using a USB attached hard drive but I need to educate/encourage the user to use OneDrive to facilitate home working.

When I run OneDrive setup on the PC and the user logs on with school userid, password and texted passcode (this user does not have a phone with GUI) as shown here: [Install and set up OneDrive on your Windows 7 PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-files-off-a-windows-7-pc-with-onedrive-b5e918be-0fd4-4095-98da-bceed57f8e0c), the connection to OneDrive/Sharepoint always fails - I did not see any specific error code. This error has occurred 4 times. The user has no problem logging on to Office 365 through a browser with this school account and password - so the user isn't entering the wrong credentials when trying to connect to OneDrive on Windows 7.

Is this a well-known authentication error when attempting to setup OneDrive on Win 7 with a work/school account? I couldn't find a description of this problem online. I couldn't see any error codes when the login/connection failed - is their somewhere I need to look to get more diagnostic information that may help explain and fix this setup problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows 7 needed to be upgraded to support TLS 1.1 and 1.2 protocols.

There are various steps I tried on the [following webpage](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392).

I think the "easyfix" option updated the Registry. A subsequent reboot allowed a successful logon attempt to the OneDrive (Sharepoint?) server.

Now the user is organising and backing up data to the OneDrive folder that the user has assigned. Once that is all done, I will migrate the user to a Windows 10 machine with all the familiar (and current) applications and access to the data on OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

The [link that you used in the question](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-files-off-a-windows-7-pc-with-onedrive-b5e918be-0fd4-4095-98da-bceed57f8e0c) contains the answer you are looking for:

> Important: Personal OneDrive desktop apps running on these operating
> systems will stop syncing to the cloud on March 1, 2022.
>
> Important: Beginning January 1, 2022, we are ending support for
> selected OneDrive desktop apps running on Windows 7, 8, and 8.1. Learn more.